# Android Admob does not show the specified app

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated Admob in my Android application.

In admob.com, I added a site which points to my Android app in the market place. The problem is, it shows some random ads. I was thinking since I have specified my android app site link, Admob should show an ad pointing to my app.

If any one can tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you created and paid for a campaign as an advertiser (under the "campaigns" tab)? This will show your ads on the Admob network. Simply integrating Admob in your app will show other people's ads in your app, for which (eventually) you will receive some money.

Comment: I have put in this in url section market://details?id=<package-name> , so i was expecting that when the ad shows in my app, it should point to my app in the market place

Comment: I think you have misunderstood Admob. If you just want a link to your app in the market place in your app why don't you just create an ImageView in your app and link with the appropriate intent?

Comment: Yes you are right...I was a bit confused....One more thing i wanted to ask, is it possible to display video using admob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Admob, you just put code in your app that gives Admob space to display their ads. What ads get displayed are decided by Admob, you have limited options to change that on the Admob website. As far as I know, there is no way to make Admob show specific ads, and the more filters you have the less ads that will be shown.

As for why it doesn't show an ad for your app, you need to set up an ad campaign with Admob, but even then you don't get to choose what ads get displayed.

And there's no point in having it show an ad for your app while inside your app. The point of ads are to get people to download your app, which they obviously already did.